# Selenium IDE for testing Drupal 7 with Media and Paragraphs

Tags: media, testing

I'm writing Selenium IDE tests for my Drupal 7 site and it's great. The issue is recording/writing tests for actions that aren't simple "clicks". I have instructions for using the RunScript action to enter text into a CKEditor box, but I've run into two more places where I can't figure out how to record a click:

- browsing for a file using the media browser provided by the Media module
- add a "paragraph" using the Paragraphs module

Has anyone made Selenium IDE tests that include either of these actions?

Thanks in advance!